# Design a big report form in Microsoft RDLC Report for at least 4 pages

Tags: report, rdlc

Microsoft RDLC Report. I have a very long form; from the database, I receive a single record with many columns. Now the problem is that I started designing the form until the page was filled, in total it would be about 4 pages. Is it possible to add the next page in the designer? Or is there another approach?

I tried to design the page on the right side of the report, but this only works when exporting to PDF.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. The solution is to open the report in XML format, and at the end, you can set the height, save, and reopen it in the designer.

```html
</ReportItems>
     <Height>75.37679cm</Height>
    <Style />
</Body>
```